# Animate tabItem on dragenter

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

Im trying to create an effect in my tabcontrol when draging over a tab I want to move it x number of pixels to the right creating a sliding effect as I drag over, but I cant seem to get the animation to fire. What am I missing here:

```
                       <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">                               
                            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <RotateTransform />
                                        <TranslateTransform />
                                        <SkewTransform />
                                        <ScaleTransform />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TabItem.DragEnter" >
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation 
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TabItem.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                                         From="0"
                                                         To="50"
                                                         Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                                         FillBehavior="Stop"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the `RenderTransform` property to a `TransformGroup` and you want to animate the `X` property of the second child of this one so the `Storyboard.TargetProperty` should be set to `RenderTransform.Children[1].X`:

```
<DoubleAnimation 
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[1].X"
    From="0"
    To="50"
    Duration="0:0:0.5"
    FillBehavior="Stop"/>
```

Your current `DoubleAnimation` should work if you set the `RenderTransform` property to a `TranslateTransform`:

```
<Setter Property="RenderTransform">
    <Setter.Value>
        <TranslateTransform />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```